# Dapper Parameter replace not working for Top

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

This is my sql

```
var maxLimit =100;
var sql = "Select Top @MaxLimit from Table WHere data =@Id"
conn.Query<Result>(sql, new  {
                Id = customerId,
                MaxLimit = maxLimit
            })
```

But I get a system error

> incorrect syntax near @MaxLimit.

Is Dapper not able to parametrize fields like Top, or Fetch?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In SQL Server any `top` expression other than a numeric constant needs to be in parentheses.

```
SELECT TOP (@MaxLimit) FROM ...
```

Comment: Only supported in 2005 and greater. (showing my age)

Answer (score 16):

Newer versions of dapper have [literal replacements](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md#literal-replacements) and they work great in this case:

```
var sql = "Select Top {=MaxLimit} from Table WHere data = @Id";
```

Comment: I like this WAY better than the old version! thnx!